# How does panopticlick detect fonts available in a browser?

Tags: jquery, flash, html, fonts

You can determine if specific a font is installed or not by checking if text in that font has a different size than normal text ([source](http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect)).

But [panopticlick.eff.org](http://panopticlick.eff.org) seems to be getting my complete list, are they just checking every they know of?  I can't see that info in the HTTP Request, is there just something in the DOM I can query for a list of available fonts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Panopticlick uses Flash to retrieve the list of fonts installed on the client's computer.

In ActionScript:

```
var installedFonts = TextField.getFontList();
getURL('javascript:flashFontList("' + escape(installedFonts) + '")', '_self');
```

Comment: @Dave: I wouldn't consider that cheating. For their purposes, it's a perfectly valid way.

Comment: I mean cheating with a :), it looks like there's a free tool for the rest of us to use too: https://github.com/gabriel/font-detect-js